# How do I enable post mortem debugging in pydev?

Tags: python, debugging, pydev

I want to make pydev enter into an interactive console mode whenever my program raises an unhandled exception but I can't figure out how to do it. As it behaves now, the exception is reported and the process is terminated immidiately.

After some searching around I found this:
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3029746&group_id=85796&atid=577332
which suggests to use pydevd.set_pm_excepthook()

However, when i add

```
import pydevd
pydevd.set_pm_excepthook()
```

to my code, I get an exception:

```
This function is now replaced by GetGlobalDebugger().setExceptHook and is now controlled by the PyDev UI.')
DeprecationWarning: This function is now replaced by GetGlobalDebugger().setExceptHook and is now controlled by the PyDev UI.
```

But:

```
GetGlobalDebugger().setExceptHook()
```

Doesn't seem to work, GetGlobalDebugger() does not exist in the global namespace.

Comment: I found out how, but it seems I can't answer my own question within 8 hours so I guess I should wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to do this programmatically... you can go to the Debug perspective > Pydev menu > Manage Exception Breakpoints

[image: GUI example]

and check 'Suspend on uncaught exceptions'. In most cases you will want to catch all kinds of exceptions (so choose "Select All") but you can also select exceptions to be managed individually.

[image: Dialog]

Comment: Oh, that's handy. Thought there should be an option like that, but didn't find it in the preferences or in debug configurations. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: What program is this in?

Comment: *Suspend on uncaught exceptions* is not the same as `pdb.post_portem(tb)` which can be called in specific situations only and governed by application's specific logic. Could you please extend your answer with information on what's an equivalent for `pdb.post_portem(tb)` in [PyDev.Debugger](https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger) for all those who want to do it programatically?

Comment: I'd like to add to Fabio's answer that you have to actually specify the Exception types that will be caught (a long checkbox column above the "Suspend on uncaught exceptions"). Otherwise after the exception occurs the main console will terminate regardless and interactive console (below the main console) won't work (shows *[Invalid Frame]: Please select frame to connect the console.* when you type something in).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so after a while I figured out the obvious, the code should be:

```
import pydevd
pydevd.GetGlobalDebugger().setExceptHook(Exception, True, False)
```

To capture any unhadled exceptions. The method can be used in other ways to enter debug mode when the program crashes, as documented in the **doc** of setExceptHook:

> Should be called to set the exceptions to be handled and whether it
>   should break on uncaught and
>           caught exceptions.
>
> Can receive a parameter to stop only on some exceptions.
>
> ```
>     E.g.:
>         set_pm_excepthook((IndexError, ValueError), True, True)
>
>         or
>
>         set_pm_excepthook(IndexError, True, False)
>
>         if passed without a parameter, will break on any exception
>
>     @param handle_exceptions: exception or tuple(exceptions)
>         The exceptions that should be handled.
>
>     @param break_on_uncaught bool
>         Whether it should break on uncaught exceptions.
>
>     @param break_on_caught: bool
>         Whether it should break on caught exceptions.
> ```

I hope this'll help others who wants to use the pydev debugger in eclipse for debugging a program after an exception has been raised.