# Pydev, how to pause on exception

Tags: python-3.x, pydev

In Visual Studio, when I run an application, it will pause and enter debug mode when an exception is caught.

How do I replicate this behaviour in Pydev?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable post mortem debugging in pydev?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899461/how-do-i-enable-post-mortem-debugging-in-pydev)

Answer (score 2):

You must enable the debug perspective.

Then, in the PyDev menu use: Manage Python Exception Breakpoints

Comment: The option is 'Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions'.