# Eclipse/Pydev debug error - [Invalid Frame]

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

When I try to use the Eclipse/Pydev interactive console in debug mode, I am getting the following error:

```
[Invalid Frame]: Please select frame to connect the console.
```

This seems like something that could easily be corrected, but I don't have much experience with this. Searching SO and google did not turn up anything helpful.

Comment: I no longer use Eclipse or Pydev, so I'm not sure if the submitted answers are valid, however I will leave this question here for reference.

Comment: Check both [Fabio's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11950838/10492167) and [my](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56277130/10492167) answer to [How do I enable post mortem debugging in pydev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899461/how-do-i-enable-post-mortem-debugging-in-pydev/56277130#56277130), this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, for the interactive console in debug mode, you need to have a frame selected -- this is the stack frame on the debug view (so, open the debug view and select the frame on which the commands you execute should be evaluated).

Comment: I get that I should select a frame, just not sure how to do that. I have the debug view open and tried executing commands after clicking on all of the items there, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the execution hadn't reached the breakpoint yet. When that happens you'll get something like:

```
Backend MacOSX is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
```